# How can I see the fingerprint of my adbkey?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, adb, ssh

You should know that Android 4.2.2 (or just before) introduced RSA key checking for adb access. – The device asks now if you want to allow access.

To avoid asking every time, the computer presents an RSA key, which can be permanently accepted.

The dialog on the phone shows the RSA key fingerprint. – On Linux, the public/secret key pair is here: `~/.android/adbkey(.pub)`.

How can I show the fingerprint of that key file? (I’m looking for a command line to do that on the Linux system.)

Comment: This is also needed when trying to verify the RSA key fingerprint presented when enabling USB debugging.

Comment: adb _is_ usb debugging @JonathanCross

Comment: Now the keywords "usb debugging" are inside this answer  :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This line will do it (found [here](http://www.shredzone.de/cilla/page/374/validating-the-android-422-rsa-fingerprint.html)):

```
awk '{print $1}' < ~/.android/adbkey.pub | openssl base64 -A -d -a | openssl md5 -c
```

Comment: `awk '{print $1}' < ~/.android/adbkey.pub | base64 --decode | md5sum` works as well

Comment: how do I run this in windows

Comment: since a commit on Nov 15 2018 (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/2dc4cabe0639c71014d729dd92eff19289429c89), adb keygen no longer generates the public key. You can use `adb pubkey ~/.android/adbkey | awk '{print $1}' \
| openssl base64 -A -a -d | openssl md5 -c | tr a-z A-Z ` to get the MD5 fingerprint. Source: https://joachimschuster.de/posts/debug-on-device-rsa-fingerprint

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
echo {public key} | base64 --decode | md5sum
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android 5 and above, the hash function used was changed to `sha256`. If your hardware is such, your could try:

```
awk '{print $1}' < ~/.android/adbkey.pub | openssl base64 -A -d -a | openssl sha256 -c | awk '{print $2}'|tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

Comment: On Android 10 I am still getting MD5.