# How do I verify that the USB debugging key fingerprint is correct?

Tags: adb, security, usb-debugging

When I try to enable USB debugging on my Android device, I am prompted with this message:

> The computer's RSA key fingerprint is:
> FE:35:23:34:...

I see the public key in `~/.android/adbkey.pub`

How can I verify that this RSA key fingerprint is correct on the computer's commandline?

Can I use `adb`?

Comment: You are using an USB connection. How likely is an interception attack on an USB cable?

Comment: @Robert Although the chances are slim, they are not zero. Given that Android developers chose to deliberately show a key fingerprint, it seems only logical to verify it before accepting, no?  Are you saying verification is impossible?

Answer (score 6):

Per [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50922/170290):

```
awk '{print $1}' < ~/.android/adbkey.pub | base64 --decode | md5sum
```